# Oracle Query - &&# variables from SQLPlus

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have successfully used &&1, &&2, &&3, etc. in my SQLPlus query, and was wondering if it is possible to use this with any Oracle query, not just through SQLPlus? 
What are these "variables" properly called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are called, Substitution Variables.  They are only for sqlplus.  See [reference documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b31189/toc.htm) If you are referring to "other queries" such as withing PL/SQL, those use bind parameters.